# Short Story where a girl with magic in a jar loses her magic when the jar is smashed

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

It's been about ten years since I read this story. It was a fantasy story in a sci-fi and fantasy collection of top stories. The story followed a boy who met a girl, and I don't remember much else except that it turned out the girl had a jar full of... finger bones? baby teeth? Some other substance? that couldn't be replaced and that gave her magic and/or protection of some kind.

For some reason, the boy decided to smash the jar, and the girl either died or lost her powers in a big, emotional moment.

I'm pretty sure it was in a short story collection alongside the story "Learning to Be Me" (Not in the book Axiomatic, however), but I could be very wrong. I know I read both of those stories very close together, and I think I only had the single collection of sci-fi and fantasy stories.

Comment: Could it have been in *The Year’s Best Science Fiction: Eighth Annual Collection*?

Comment: 'Learning To Be Me' has been repeatedly collected. Perhaps one of these will jog your memory; http://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?40532

Comment: ["Learning to Be Me"](http://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?40532) has appeared under [these covers](http://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/titlecovers.cgi?40532). See anything familiar?

Comment: “A Tooth for Every Child” maybe? It’s got “tooth” in the name and appeared together with “Learning to Be Me”?

Comment: @user14111 - Though what little information I can find insists that it is about a boy named Keith who gives birth to a lobster that’s his mother…or something.

Comment: I think it was in The Year's Best Science Fiction: Eighth Annual Collection. The cover, title and publisher all seem right. But looking through the list of stories in there, none of them ring a bell. I'll have to get that book and see if I can find it in there.

Comment: @Dmortensen But that's a science fiction anthology, and the story you described sounds like fantasy. Any reason it would be in a science fiction book? Does the story have some "sciencey" aspect you haven't mentioned?

Comment: The Amazon page for that book has a review with a short list of descriptions.

Answer (score 10):

I actually found the story, a couple of weeks ago. It was "[Nine Fingered Maria](http://podcastle.org/2009/06/24/podcastle-58-nine-fingered-maria/)", by Hillary Moon Murphy. The jar had the bones of her amputated little finger in it. It was published in [*New Voices in Science Fiction*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?23784) before being released as a podiocast read by Christopher Reynaga.

Comment: You should be able to accept your own answer. :) I also updated the entry for *New Voices in Science Fiction* on ISFDB to include the story among its contents, although it has to go through a moderator first.

Comment: Thanks for coming back and answering this. :-)